# CiviVolunteer 2.2 - problem with missing profile

Tags: civievent, 4.7, civivolunteer

I installed the latest Civivolunteer 2.2 with 4.7.24. First time, not an upgrade. When I click the 'Volunteers' tab in an event I get the error message 'The requested profile (gid=36) is disabled OR...' (etc etc). I tried uninstalling, clearing all caches and re-installing but still a problem.  The profile with gid of 36 does not exist.  If I could figure out how to create a profile with gid of 36 I would but can't see where they are stored in the db - another user fixed the problem this way.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are in the table civicrm_uf_group, and the table civicrm_uf_field contains the relevant fields for the profile. This does not answer your main question, but may help you workaround.

Comment: Thanks Pete, very helpful, like looking for a needle in a haystack - so useful to know which haystack.  This enabled me to fix the problem so +1 answer in my view!

Comment: did you +1 it? not showing to me

Comment: if you can both Accept and +1 it then StackExchange is happy. otherwise it keeps pushing the item back up the list as having no useful answers